# How to share my project via GIT if I have git server in internet?

Tags: windows, eclipse, git, eclipse-plugin, github

I know, that its easy to share my project with team in eclipse, but it creates local git server.
I created an account in a site like github and know I have git repository in internet (I have git url, login and password).
And I have my project in eclipse. How to share it with my friend if he also have git account in my server?

Comment: I also have to use SSH connection and generated my private and public keys. Where to use them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Github_Tutorial for an example of working with EGit and GitHub, and http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Considerations_for_Git_Repositories_to_be_used_in_Eclipse for a discussion on creating local repositories for use with your workspace in general.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if you host your project from github. You can simple release you project name to other users and they can find it and howto from GitHub.

Secondly, if you can copy command from you host (GITHUB like 'git clone XXXXXXXXXX'. That's the basic command to get local copy from Github.

Finally. Don't forget to push your update and pull other's back from Github.